# spark DataFrameWriter in the latest version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We want to upgrade to the latest version of spark and scala. I am pretty new to scala and want to know how to rewrite below code as DataFrameWriter in the latest version takes type parameters.

Here is how we are specifying using the old version .

```
def saveText(fs: FileSystem, path: String, writer: 
    DataFrameWriter): Unit = {
    val fullPath = fs.getFullPath(path)
    writer.text(fullPath)
}
```

Comment: You usually get the `DataFrameWriter` instance using a reference of `DataFrame` something like `df.write`, hence type parameter is not required. I'm eager to know how are you generating reference of `DataFrameWriter` in you code. In case you use RDDs you can convert it to DataFrame and write it using `rdd.toDF().write.text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scala, when you have a parameterized type `A[T]` you can refer to "A parameterized by anything" as `A[_]`. Therefore, your function can be as simple as:

```
def saveText(fs: FileSystem, path: String, writer: DataFrameWriter[_]): Unit = 
  writer.text(fs.getFullPath(path))
```